# how to prevent rapid and automatically http request for insert content on web page?example massive blog posts

Tags: httprequest

how to prevent rapid and automaticaly http request for insert content on web page? For example I have a blog. How prevent that a program automatically insert massive blog posts? I want only human can insert blog post or a api function provide by my web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using recaptcha for preventing bots to add content on your blog
http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: Ok thanks. Instead for prevent program that automatically forge http request to different pages? For example, a program each 1sec send request to different page. I want count user visitors page but I want prevent that program visit all pages of my site for have hight score visit.

Comment: Look for something called robots.txt. Inside it you have a list of well known bad and good bots. Research on how to enable it on your blog and I think you're done!